# Where to find boost's skeleton for autopackage?

Tags: boost

I'm using autopackage to create an installer.
The installer contain binary files (closed source project). The project depends of some boost libraries (date_time, thread etc.).
Other dependences work fine:

```
require @haxx.se/libcurl 4
require @openssl.org/openssl 0.9
```

But I didn't found skeleton file(s) for boost libraries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create it by yourself! It's easy.
Example:

```
# Package skeleton for the boost thread

[Meta]
RootName: @boost.org/boost_thread
DisplayName: Boost thread C++ library
ShortName: libboost_thread
Skeleton-Version: 1

[Notes]
Does not set SOFTWARE_VERSIONS

[Test]
INTERFACE_VERSIONS=$( testForLib -i libboost_thread.so)

if [ -z $INTERFACE_VERSIONS ]
then
INTERFACE_VERSIONS=$( testForLib -i libboost_thread-mt.so)
fi

if [ -z $INTERFACE_VERSIONS ]
then
INTERFACE_VERSIONS=$( testForLib -i libboost_thread-gcc.so)
fi

if [ -z $INTERFACE_VERSIONS ]
then
INTERFACE_VERSIONS=$( testForLib -i libboost_thread-gcc-mt.so)
fi

if [ -z $INTERFACE_VERSIONS ]
then
INTERFACE_VERSIONS=$( testForLib -i libboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_33_1.so)
fi

if [ -z $INTERFACE_VERSIONS ]
then
INTERFACE_VERSIONS=$( testForLib -i libboost_thread-gcc-1_33_1.so)
fi
```